# Evaluation of logical operand

Tags: c

If I have the following:

```
int a = -10 && 0;
```

then does C evaluate `-10` as `1` because `-10` is different from `0` and then make
the comparation between `1 && 0` to get `0` as result?
Or does let `-10` and make the comparation as written?

Instead if I write:

```
int c = 10;
int b = 11;

int res = c > 10 && b == 11;
```

then the C make this:

`c > 10` is false so it evaluates to `0` while
`b == 11` is true so it evaluates to `1`

then the expression is:

`0 && 1` with `0` as result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operator `&&` and `||` has *short circuit behavior*<sup>**1**</sup>. In

```
int a = -10 && 0;
```

since left operand is `-10`, which  is non-zero and hence `true`, therefore right operand, i.e `0` is checked. In

```
int res = c > 10 && b == 11;
```

since left operand is evaluated to `false`, right operand is not evaluated.

---

<sup>**1** C11 6.5.13 (p4): *If the first operand compares equal to `0`, the second operand is not evaluated.*</sup>

Comment: If anyone is interested: The C99 standard defines this in section 6.5.13, paragraphs 3 & 4.

Comment: Yes, but is -10 evaluated to 1 before making the &&?

Comment: @xdevel2000 read the text; they are compared against `0` . It's not explicitly stated how the compiler must store the result of each comparison against 0, just so long as the result of the entire expression is correct.

Comment: @xdevel2000; Any non-zero value is evaluated to `true`. `-10` is compared against `0` and hence the expression evaluated to `true`. You can rewrite the first statement as `int a = (-10 == 0) && (0 == 0); `

Comment: @haccks, so if you write (-10 == 0) it means that -10 is not compared as written but what is compared is the result of (-10 == 0) that is 1.

Comment: @xdevel2000; There was a typo in my last comment. I mean to say: *You can rewrite the first statement as int `a = (-10 != 0) && (0 != 0);`*

Answer (score 1):

For

```
int a = -10&&0;
```

`-10` is treated as higher logic(1). However, result still be 0.

Comment: Yes but is -10 evaluated to 1 before making the &&?

Comment: No. -10 is non-zero and hence it is treated as true.